# How can i return raw bytes from ASP.NET web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

If the WebMethod returns string it gets serialized to xml.

I want to return `byte[]` with responding ContentType - can I also specify it?.

Can it be done in ASP.NET web service web method?

Answer (score 2):

ASMX web services use SOAP and the content type will always be `application/soap+xml` and the content represent `xml`. Even if you return a `byte[]` from your method this array will be base64 encoded into the soap body.

Comment: So there is no way to bypass this limitation? :)

Comment: It's not a limitation, it's part of the standard. If you don't want to return a response that a SOAP client can understand, then don't use a SOAP (ASMX) page in the first place - use one of the more generic HTTP handlers and write to the Response object.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a byte array from a web service, but it will still be serialised into the response message. (Typically as base-64 in a SOAP XML response.)

If you want to return only the binary content you shouldn't use a web service. Instead you can use `Response.BinaryWrite` with a regular page with no html content, or `context.BinaryWrite` in a http handler.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a web service, use a Generic Handler (.ashx).

A Generic Handler accepts get/post requests and gives you the ability to completely control the output via the HttpContext.

I typically use these for sending files (pdfs, etc) to the browser.