# can an ASMX web service response back with Response.BinaryWrite?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms, asmx

Instead of returning a binary stream (MTOM/Base64 encoded) in the web-method itself (as SOAP XML) e.g:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] Download(string FileName)
....
return byteArray;
```

Can this method respond somehow with (maybe via the `Server` object)?:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
```

Pseudo:

```
[WebMethod]
public DownloadBinaryWrite(string FileName)
...
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
```

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1975268/114267

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to change the return type to void since we're going to be writing directly to the response, and you need to manually set the content type and end the response so that it doesn't continue processing and send more data.

```
[WebMethod]
public void Download(string FileName)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(imagebytes);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Note that WebMethod is [not really supported](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) these days, you should be switching to [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) (if you need SOAP support).

Comment: I tried it out and you are correct. Still seems kind of odd to send a soapaction not get back a soap response. Certainly not interoperable with general SOAP clients, but if you don't need that why care about it. If the caller expects SOAP (like a .NET Web Reference) it might get confused (and no I did not try it out that far; maybe it would work but seems unlikely).

Comment: `Response` is not recognize as valid object.

Comment: @zig Then use `HttpContext.Current.Response`

Comment: Thanks! BTW, why do we need that `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()`?

Comment: @zig It might be possible to remove it. But ending the response ensures that no extra data gets written to the client (which might corrupt the file), and the current thread will end because it will throw a ThreadAbortException.

Comment: -1 for suggesting Web API in answer to a SOAP question. Otherwise I would have upvoted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, That was rather a useful information to me. BTW, how does my question is not related to 'asp.net' since you have removed the tag?

Comment: It's not general ASP.NET - it's "ASP.NET Web Services", more accurately known as "ASMX". That's the tag I added. Also, the Web API part would have been ok as "and, if you don't require SOAP, you could consider Web API".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Updated my answer. Didn't really notice that SOAP support was a requirement in the first place.

Comment: Not so much a requirement, as, that's what he was using. And, I like your "not really supported" link.

Comment: @JohnSaunders after [a spirited back and forth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350349/what-is-the-request-life-cycle-for-asynchronous-ajax-asp-net-page-method-calls) we have arrived at the understanding that the `WebMethodAttribute` is not limited only to web services but also is used in other contexts in `System.Web.Extensions`. Since MSDN doesnt specify much other than using it with ASMX it's easy to lump Page Methods in there, for which Web API is a good alternative. It's possible OP is using ASMX + AJAX for something that can be solved with AJAX only and doesn't require WCF + AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do BinaryWrite you probably want to write a separate IHttpHandler instead of a web method. Web methods are oriented around SOAP stuff, so hacking them into custom responses, while possible, is kind of odd.

Comment: I need to keep that in the web service itself. or at-least in the same ASMX (I would rather avoid that).