# What is the request life cycle for asynchronous (ajax) ASP.NET Page Method calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

What is the application event/processing timeline for an asynchronous request made to a page method on a Web Form? Looking for a canonical answer or resource.

Note: This is a request for information about how ASP.NET AJAX handles incoming requests made to web services exposed to client script [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.100).aspx) in the section named "Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page." This is not to be confused with the page life cycle. It should also be mentioned that `[WebMethod]` and `[ScriptMethod]` are features of ASP.NET AJAX, and not XML Web Services, as one might infer when reading certain MSDN documentation, examples of which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: This is a question about a *page method*, not a normal request to a page. The page life cycle does not apply to this type of request.

Comment: Are you talking about [WebMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I am talking about a page method, which is one specific use of the WebMethod attribute, where a method on an ASP.NET WebForm is decorated with the attribute.

Comment: And why do you want to know this? I'm not saying it's not a good idea to have that all written down somewhere, but we might be able to answer your underlying question if you tell us why.

Comment: I want to know this because page methods are used in nearly every WebForms application that uses AJAX to communicate with the server, and I am having difficulty finding any resource available on the internet about how it works under the hood. I didn't want to limit the question to my specific use case, I wanted to request a canonical answer to highlight this need and create a reference point for others looking for the same thing.

Comment: As for my specific use case, I am resolving dependencies out of a Windsor container for use in page methods, and I want to know what events are available for me to hook into in order to trigger the release of the objects, so that I don't have to clutter up my code by explicitly releasing them after every resolution. Understanding the life cycle of the request would go a long way in understanding how to design this properly, or if I need to go a different direction.

Comment: You definitely *should* go a different direction, as [Microsoft no longer supports XML Web Services (`ScriptMethod` and `WebMethod`)](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/). Instead, you should be moving to [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). I understand that's not always feasible in legacy applications, but for new development (which it sounds like you're doing), that's what you should do (or use [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)).

Comment: Putting aside the fact that I am working on a .NET 3.5 app that cannot support an ApiController, your suggestions do not apply. I am not creating an .asmx service. I am not creating a service at all. I am using the WebMethod attribute on a method of a page, so that ASP.NET AJAX will expose an endpoint for incoming XMLHttpRequests. This is the same mechanism that is used to AJAX-enable a WCF service, which is supported. There is no evidence to suggest that page methods are not supported.

Comment: If you read the link I provided, it does explain that Microsoft doesn't support them. It applies not only to ASMX, but to any usage of `[WebMethod]` or `[ScriptMethod]`. Though I agree-if you're on 3.5, you don't have much choice. I can't definitely tell you the lifecycle, but my guess is that you get the standard lifecycle methods from `global.asax` and your actual `WebMethod`, and that's it. I don't think it has a complicated lifecycle like a `Page`, because there's no control hierarchy or data binding going on.

Comment: So you're telling me that when I put the WebMethod attribute on a codebehind method, it creates an XML Web Service?

Comment: Yes. XML Web Service is the name of the technology that encompasses `[WebMethod]` and `[ScriptMethod]`. It's not a name you hear very often, but that's specifically what MSDN calls it. Look at the link in the very first comment I wrote. It specifically says "Methods within a class that have this attribute [WebMethod] set are called XML Web service methods."

Comment: XML Web Services use the XmlSerializer, and WCF services use the DataContractSerializer. But I'm not creating an asmx service with methods with this attribute on it, which is what the example in the "XML Web service methods" section does. I don't have the option to use WCF because there is no service in the first place. Itspossible that ASP.NET is creating an asmx service proxy to expose the endpoint under the hood, but it's equally likely it's doing it via WCF. Incidentally, a canonical answer to my question would answer this question :)

Comment: My gut suspicion is that having WebMethod in a code behind is no different than having it in an ASMX, and that any and all of use `WebMethod` is no longer supported. It's not really relevant what they use to serialize the XML compared to WCF. Anyways, I doubt you're likely to get the answer to this question as it requires deep knowledge of an area of ASP.NET that wasn't developed in the open. Perhaps you might have better luck checking in some Microsoft channels such as Jabber or Twitter (or emailing one of them), and then posting an answer here if you get a good response.

Comment: So it turns out that the WebMethod attribute is alive and well. It's used to signify a destination for the handler that handles incoming application/json requests to the server. The MSDN documentation is misleading because it only talks about how to use it with an XML Web Service, but there's no service at all, just an HTTP request when dispatching to a page method.

Comment: Source: System.Web.Extensions

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Could you elaborate on your conclusion that `WebMethodAttribute` is "alive and well"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I read through the System.Web.Extensions source as a result of this thread. The `WebMethodAttribute` is used in separate contexts in the framework. It's used to AJAX-enable an .asmx service, but it's also used in page methods to tell ASP.NET that it's a destination for incoming JSON requests. When ASP.NET sees an incoming JSON request it goes through and looks using various criteria (one of which is looking for methods that are decorated with the attribute) to find where it should route the request. It's the .asmx technology that's legacy, not all usages of the attribute.

Comment: As for it being "alive and well," before Web API came out, page methods were the preferred way (over page callbacks) to expose an endpoint to client script on your page in WebForms. It's going to be quite a while before every WebForms app out there using AJAX is using Web API.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Did you notice that page methods are the same technology as using [ScriptMethod] on an asmx file?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Page methods are unique in that they do not require an additional server-side web service to be created and hosted. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx#S5), specifically "Page Methods vs. Web Service Methods" explains the differences. They, along with WCF, do share _ASP.NET AJAX_  technology. [This MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a diagram labeled "AJAX Client Architecture" which shows that there is a common "Web Service Communication Layer" that *all* AJAX requests go through.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Actually, client architecture is not the appropriate diagram, the server architecture is. The client architecture is specifically for when you are using the Microsoft Ajax library, or the ScriptManager proxies.

Comment: There is no "Server Architecture" diagram. Are you referring to the one with the "BLL"? That's a diagram of the application, not of the service technology. Page Methods use _exactly_ the same technology as ASMX services. They only difference is that you don't have to create a separate .asmx file.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The first article does in fact show a difference. It explains how requests to asmx services are intercepted by an HTTP handler, whereas page methods are handled by a script HTTP module. If that isn't enough for you, please refer to the "AJAX Server Architecture" diagram, which exists in the second link mentioned in my original comment. It's very telling that WCF and ASMX are in one group, while page methods are in a completely different group. Again, this common functionality you are referring to is ASP.NET AJAX, not any communication or service technology.