# Sending file via ajax call is 4 times the size it is

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, file, ftp

I've got a Javascript ajax function that calls a c# webservice to download a zip file.  The zip file is then extracted in Javascript and I then use that data.

The webservice goes to an FTP site and downloads a file that's about 2.6MB and sends that back to the ajax function.  However, when ajax gets the file, it's about 4 times as big!

Here's an image with the original file size:

[Showing original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UjNI.png)

As you can see, it's about 2.6 MB

I am downloading it using this code:

```
public static byte[] DownloadFTPFile(string ftpUrl, string userName, string password, bool useSsl, bool allowInvalidCertificate, bool useActiveFtp)
    {

            FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpUrl, userName, password, useSsl, allowInvalidCertificate, useActiveFtp);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                reader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                bytes = memstream.ToArray();
            }

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            return bytes;

    }
```

The webservice that calls the above looks like this:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public byte[] GetLatestFile()
    {

            return DownloadFTPFile(ftpUrl, userName, password, useSsl, allowInvalidCertificate, useActiveFtp)
    }
```

Finally, here's the ajax Javascript code that actually asks for that file, and then unzips it using zip.js:

```
function GetMyData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../WebServices/MyWebServiceURL.asmx/GetLatestFile',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == 0) {
                    logOut();
                } else {
                    UnpackData(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //Handle error
            }
        });
    }

    function UnpackData(string) {
        var responseArray = new Uint8Array(string);
        var blobData = new Blob([responseArray], {
            type: 'application/zip'
        });
        zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(blobData), function (zipReader) {
            zipReader.workerScriptsPath = "../Javascript/";
            zipReader.getEntries(function (entries) {
                if (entries.length) {
                    entries[0].getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function (data) {
                        DoSomethingWithUnpackedData(data);
                        zipReader.close(function () {
                        });

                    }, function (current, total) {
                    });
                }
            });
        }, function (error) {
            // onerror callback
        });            
    }

    function DoSomethingWithUnpackedData(data) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
```

Here, the responseArray variable contains exactly the correct number of bytes (about 2.6 MB) - This all works really well, but if I examine the traffic then the file which was originally 2.6MB is now being transferred at a rather larger 8.9MB:

[Website debugger showing increased file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLNIc.png)

I think this might be something to do with the fact that I am returning it as a byte array, but I'm not sure.  Does anyone know a) why the file returned is approx. 4 times the original size, b) how I can ensure that this is sent / received as the original size while c) still being able to get zip.js to unpack it properly.

I'm tearing my hair out over this one, so any advice someone can offer me regarding where I'm going wrong is much appreciated!

Tom.

To clarify a point here, the problem is NOT that there is an issue with the zip file that's received by the Ajax call, as such.  That zip file unzips perfectly (unzipped it's about 20MB of data).  The thing that I'm struggling with is the fact that the zip file is 2.5MB, but the above method transfers 9MB of data to the client machine.  For reasons of keeping my site as streamlined as possible, if the original zip file is 2.5MB big, I would, of course, rather that 2.5MB of data is transferred to the client machine for unzipping and not the rather odd 9MB of data that's currently being transferred.

Comment: The file is probably compressed and the download is GZIP.  So you are getting the uncompressed data.

Comment: Can you unzip file with a different zip application?There are different versions of ZIP files.Not all can be unzipped with every tools.  We need to determine if the issue is you didn't get the entire file or the zip is not compatible with you tools.  For example I've seen people add files to an existing zip and then some tools do not recognize the added files.I also seen issue years ago where the zip file was create on a unix file system and then wouldn't unzip on a VMS operating system.  but then worked on Windows.To solve issue we performed the zip on Windows before saving on network drive.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thanks for you comments - however the file I'm getting is definitely not uncompressed data as the uncompressed file size is nearly 20MB big.  The compressed size is 2.5MB.  But when it's transferred to the client with the ajax call, the size is around 9MB big.  Also, when I look at the data that's been received by the ajax call, it's as garbled as I would expect a zip file to be, but when I pass it to zip.js to unpack then there are no errors indicating that it's not a zip file, and the output from zip.js is the unpacked file exactly as I would expect it.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: It is a base64 string which is kind of in the middle of a compress file and the original size.  When we had issues moving zip from unix to vms we found the issue was partitioning of the network drive.   The zip format was using the partitioning of the drive and wouldn't unzip when the partitioning was different.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, @jdweng, this problem isn't that I can't unzip it.  The above process works really well: file is downloaded from FTP, byte array is sent to the client, the client passes it to zip.js, zip.js extracts it and sends the unzipped data to my function.  This works perfectly.  The issue is that the zip file on the FTP site is 2.5MB, but the above method takes 9MB to send it to the client.  While this all works I would rather the 2.5MB file is transferred via the Ajax call at 2.5MB so it's more streamlined and I don't know why it's actually taking around 9MB

Comment: Can you make a DVD of the files on the server and move to the local machine.  Then compare your downloaded file with the DVD file using beyond compare.  Find out if you got the entire file or if bytes in file changed.  I believe the block sizes in the zip are the sector size of the drive where the file came from.  Our problem was the zip utility we were using wasn't tested for all combinations of block sizes.

Comment: Hi again @jdweng.  Just to clarify, the zip file extracts fine.  There is no problem with the zip file. It uncompresses quickly and without problems.  The problem is that the file is 2.5MB originally, but the browser / client is receiving around 9MB data which it then (successfully) uncompresses.  I am trying to figure out why it's 9MB data being transferred to the client machine, and not 2.5MB.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl - thanks for your comments.  You mention that the file will not magically re-compress itself, and I totally agree, but that's not the problem.  I'm not re-compressing it at any stage, and am only un-compressing it when it reaches the client's machine.  Let's take the fact that it happens to be a zip-file out of the equation, for the moment, and we are left with this: I ask FTP for a file of X size, I send it to the client using a web-service, the amount of data being sent to the client machine is X multiplied by 4 (approx.).  That's the problem I am having, you see.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - I tried debugging by trying a completely different file.  I got the SAME process to try and download a PDF from the FTP site that I put there (have stopped using a ZIP in this example as it seems to be causing confusion about what the problem is).  The size of the file on the FTP site is 480,587 bytes. The DownloadFTPFile function gets exactly 480,587 bytes in a byte array.  So I know that's working.  The amount of data transferred to the client machine in the Ajax call in GetMyData according to the network monitor is...1,712,070 bytes of data.  Again, approx 4 times too much.

Comment: I should also point out that the responseArray variable in the UnpackData Javascript function, in this experiment, is an array of exactly 480,587 bytes. So, the file size on the FTP site is 480,587 bytes.  The bytes that are downloaded in the DownloadFTPFile c# function is 480,587 bytes, the amount of data transferred to the client machine is a comparatively large 1,712,070 bytes, but the responseArray variable in the UnpackData function is an array of 480,587 bytes.  My problem is, why is 1,712,070 bytes being transferred when the actual file size is far smaller, and what can I do to stop it?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl - the blob-size is 480,587 bytes.  :-)  (That's the size of the blobData variable)

Comment: OK, with all that information, your question can probably be a way more clear, if you edit it now.

Comment: Though, this is probably the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975268/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Thanks, but the title of the question is "Sending file via ajax call is 4 times the size it is" the statement right at the top is "The webservice goes to an FTP site and downloads a file that's about 2.6MB and sends that back to the ajax function. However, when ajax gets the file, it's about 4 times as big!" and the question at the bottom "Does anyone know a) why the file returned is approx. 4 times the original size" are reasonably clear, (along with all the code showing the route of the file from the FTP to the client)? If not, am not sure how I can be clearer?

Comment: This: *"when ajax gets the file, it's about 4 times as big"* – Your Java Script code gets the file with its original size, while at least to me, this sentence suggests something different.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks.  Have edited as you suggested.

Comment: Does the link above answer your question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - It gave me the lead I was looking for.  Thanks!  In short, for anyone else looking to solve the problem, instead of using a webservice I used an ASHX file to return the data (remembering to set the responseType as 'blob') and then passed that to the zip.js which managed to unzip it, and the file-size being transferred was exactly the correct size.  Very happy!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who needs to know, it turns out that a webservice is not designed to transfer files this way.  In the end, I created an ASHX function to return the file as a blob.  This ensured that the file size being sent was exactly the same as the original file size!

Kudos to @MartinPrikryl for pointing me in the right direction!